# How to create lines of student test information from a txt file using python

Tags: python

So far this is what I have from the comments but it doesn't run.

```
with open('score_report.txt') as in_file, open('score_report.txt','w') as out_file:
    f = iter(in_file) 
    while True:
        try:
            name = next(f)
            scores = next(f)
        except StopIteration:
            break
        s = scores.strip('[]\n').split(', ')
        scores1 = tuple(map(int, s))
        out_file.write('{}\t{}\t{}\t{}\n'.format(name.strip(),
                                                 min(scores1),
                                                 max(scores1),
                                                 sum(scores1)/len(scores1)))
```

Is there a problem with how it is that I'm not seeing? I need it to print student score reports on separate lines.

```
Smith, Jane
[77, 91, 70, 93, 73, 87]
Doe, John
[90, 83, 94, 77, 88, 95, 73]
Jones, David
[99, 80, 95, 70, 83, 99, 78]
```

Your program is to print to a file called score_report.txt one line for each student containing their name, the maximum score, their minimum score, and their average score, where each item is separated from the next by a tab.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) function to create the pairs of consecutive lines then use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html) to convert the list string to a list object :

```
from itertools import tee
with open('file_name') as in_file,open('score_report.txt','w') as out_file:
   f1,f2 = tee(in_file)
   next(f2)
   for name , scores in zip(f1,f2):
       scores = ast.literal_eval(scores.strip())
       out_file.write('{}\t{}\t{}\t{}'.format(
                                              name.strip(),
                                              min(scores),
                                              max(scores),
                                              sum(scores)/len(scores)))
```

Note that since file objects are iterator here using [`itertools.tee`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.tee) you can create 2 independent iterator form your file object then use next to consume the first item of one of the iterators then use zip to create the relative pairs.

Comment: you lack a `)` and an import maybe

Comment: most of all, if I am not mistaken, `tee` returns **indpendent iterators** so even if you advance f2 by one step, f1 will re-read the next line. Probably, it would be better to revert to the good ol' `f1=iter(in_file); f2=f1; next(f2)...`

Comment: @Pynchia No that's exactly what `tee` is for.By assigning an iterator to another one ` f2=f1` actually you will create 2 reference to one object and by traversing one of them you will consume the others too.

Comment: Are you saying this is what you want: `>>> l=['Smith, Jane', [77, 91, 70, 93, 73, 87], 'Doe John', [90, 83, 94, 77, 88, 95, 73], 'Jones, David', [99, 80, 95, 70, 83, 99, 78]]` `>>> f1,f2 = tee(l)` `>>> next(f2)` `>>> [z for z in zip(f1,f2)]` `[('Smith, Jane', [77, 91, 70, 93, 73, 87]), ([77, 91, 70, 93, 73, 87], 'Doe John'), ('Doe John', [90, 83, 94, 77, 88, 95, 73]), ([90, 83, 94, 77, 88, 95, 73], 'Jones, David'), ('Jones, David', [99, 80, 95, 70, 83, 99, 78])]`

Comment: No, the output file you got was right, i just can get it to run. I have score report in in_file and out_file, but I cant get it to run.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution

```
with open('file_name') as in_file, open('score_report.txt','w') as out_file:
    f = iter(in_file) 
    while True:
        try:
            name = next(f)
            scores = next(f)
        except StopIteration:
            break
        s = scores.strip('[]\n').split(', ')
        iscores = tuple(map(int, s))
        out_file.write('{}\t{}\t{}\t{}\n'.format(name.strip(),
                                                 min(iscores),
                                                 max(iscores),
                                                 sum(iscores)/len(iscores)))
```

which with an input file of

```
Smith, Jane
[77, 91, 70, 93, 73, 87]
Doe, John
[90, 83, 94, 77, 88, 95, 73]
Jones, David
[99, 80, 95, 70, 83, 99, 78]
```

produces an output file of

```
Smith, Jane 70  93  81.83333333333333
Doe, John   73  95  85.71428571428571
Jones, David    70  99  86.28571428571429
```

Comment: What would the fist four lines of code look like when you are reading in the file with out file?

Comment: I don't understand the question, please elaborate

Comment: I wanted to know what the lines of code are to read in the file?

Comment: How do I open('file_name') as in_file, open('score_report.txt','w') as out_file: , or more to the point what would this look like in Python code?

Comment: @Crash917 -  that is exactly how it would look like in python

Comment: @Crash917 that is python code... it replaces your code entirely. I really have a hard time getting the question, I am sorry, I am dumb. Copy and paste it into your python program, then run it (provided the input file is available)

Comment: Thank you for your output on my question.

Comment: if you think my answer solves your problem correctly and better than others', please mark it as accepted. Thank you. Let me know if I can help with anything else otherwise.